# In angular how I can make edit button to edit profile form

Tags: html, typescript, forms, components, formgroups

["this is my output"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN6uy.png)["the rest of my code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBFUp.png)["this is my code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wjjE.png)In angular how I can make edit button to edit profile form while form is disabled and convert this edit button to save button and make from enabled to save this changes and come back disabled after that ...thanks alot?

Comment: Your question lacks more context, there are many ways of doing what you are asking, could edit the post and add what you have tried so far? this way we will be able to provide you with a better answer.

Comment: I have edited my question and sent images for my code